# Reusing buffers provided for write in Netty

Tags: netty

I'm trying to implement streaming using Netty 4.0.25 and have this setup (reduced pseudo-code). My intent is avoid copying as much as possible and I have also explored using `ChunkedWriteHandler` but it does not seem to be suitable for my use case.

```
public ResponseChannel implements WritableByteChannel {
  @Override    
  public int write(ByteBuffer src) {
    int bytesWritten = src.remaining();
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(src);
    ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultHttpContent(buf));
    return bytesWritten;
  }
}
```

For the moment, let's ignore channel writability and assume that we won't go OOM if we write `src.remaining()` and also ignore write failures in the future (This is reduced code and I handle all of those cases in the longer version).

Since I'm wrapping `src` here, the same underlying bytes are being used by the `ByteBuf` too and I should not change it before the bytes are actually sent out. So my question is, when is `src` available for reuse? Immediately ? Or should I attach a listener to the future of the write and mark it reusable when `operationComplete()` of the listener gets invoked?

If it is not available for reuse immediately, then the semantic of returning `bytesWritten` would be wrong too (since the caller can always clear the `ByteBuffer` on return and write new data before the original bytes are written to the network).

My pipeline is

```
ch.pipeline()
  .addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec())
  .addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 10))
  .addLast("processor", new NettyMessageProcessor());`
```

I have chunked transfer encoding and as far as I can tell from `HttpObjectEncoder`, a copy is not created in case of chunked encoding (looks like a copy is created if it is not chunked encoding, so if I didn't have chunked transfer encoding - `src` would be available for immediate reuse).

Answer (score 2):

Norman answered this question on the Netty discussion google group.

TL;DR version is that the bytes in `src` are not considered free until the `operationComplete()` of a `ChannelFutureListener` attached to the `ChannelFuture` of the write is called.

Discussion on google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netty/ofj5u1Kzg6I).